# Mutually exclusive group with a choice and optional

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to achieve a command that has two 'modes' like this:

```
cmd --list
```

or

```
cmd option --flag -abc
```

In other words, either the user specifies the `--list` option or the parser 'chooses' the default path. The default path should be a choice from a known set of elements.

I have failed to do this with either mutually exclusive groups (since you can only specify one command that way if I'm not mistaken) as well as subcommands (they always have to have a name and I did not manage to make them a choice).

Edit: Here's what I have tried:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
mut_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

mut_group.add_argument('--list', action='store_true')
mut_group.add_argument('choice', choices=['foo', 'bar'])
```

This doesn't even compile but kinda shows what I want to achieve. Note that I also want to add other arguments when the user has typed in one of the `choices` but not after the list.
Ideally, this allows me to type `prog --list` and `prog foo --some-other-flag` but also `prog bar --some-other-flag`

Comment: please show what you have tried so far (some not correct working code)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into ArgParse's [`sub-commands`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). I think it is quite close to what you'd like to accomplish.

Example:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='example')
parser.add_argument('--list', action='store_true')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', required=False)

# create the parser for the "foo" command
subparser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo', help='foo help')
subparser_foo.add_argument('--something', type=int, help='something help')

# create the parser for the "bar" command
subparser_bar = subparsers.add_parser('bar', help='bar help')
subparser_bar.add_argument('--another', help='another help')
```

Test runs:

```py
>>> parser.parse_args('--list'.split())
Namespace(list=True)

>>> parser.parse_args('foo --something 3'.split())
Namespace(list=False, something=3)

>>> parser.parse_args('--help'.split())
usage: example [-h] [--list] {foo,bar} ...

positional arguments:
  {foo,bar}   sub-command help
    foo       foo help
    bar       bar help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --list

>>> parser.parse_args('foo --help'.split())
usage: example foo [-h] [--something SOMETHING]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --something SOMETHING
                        something help
```

Note however that, with the above, `--list` is *not* incompatible with either of the sub-commands. For example:

```py
>>> parser.parse_args('--list foo'.split())
Namespace(list=True, something=None)
```

This is not exactly what you want, but is kind of the same as what `--help` does (you can also do `program --help foo`, which by default ignores `foo`, whereas `program foo --help` gives you a help for the sub-command `foo`).

Depending on what you want to do for `--list`, you might want to make it a sub-command itself, following the pattern above (and removing the `--`, since then it is not an option but a sub-command).

Answer (score 2):

I probably should insist on you giving us the "doesnt even compile" error.  But I need to explain it anyways:

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: mut_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
   ...: mut_group.add_argument('--list', action='store_true')
   ...: mut_group.add_argument('choice', choices=['foo', 'bar'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional
```

To be mutually_exclusive the arguments need to be optional.  Your `choice` as a `positional` is required.  We can make it optional by using '?' nargs:

```
In [4]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: mut_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
   ...: mut_group.add_argument('--list', action='store_true');
   ...: mut_group.add_argument('choice', choices=['foo', 'bar'], nargs='?');  # should have default as well
In [5]: parser.parse_args(['--list'])
Out[5]: Namespace(choice=None, list=True)
In [6]: parser.parse_args(['foo'])
Out[6]: Namespace(choice='foo', list=False)
In [7]: parser.parse_args(['bar'])
Out[7]: Namespace(choice='bar', list=False)
```

Your requirements look a lot more like the `subcommands` case.

```
In [8]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: sub = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')  # optional required=True
   ...: s1 = sub.add_parser('list')
   ...: s2 = sub.add_parser('foo')
   ...: s3 = sub.add_parser('bar')
   ...: s2.add_argument('--abc')

In [9]: parser.parse_args('list'.split())
Out[9]: Namespace(cmd='list')
In [10]: parser.parse_args('foo --abc 2'.split())
Out[10]: Namespace(abc='2', cmd='foo')
In [11]: parser.parse_args('bar'.split())
Out[11]: Namespace(cmd='bar')
```

Here `list` is one of the subparsers. And its use can be found in the `cmd` attribute.

In the original `argparse` versions, the `subparsers` were required.  Now it is possible to omit it.

Changing `list` back to flagged:

```
In [12]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...: parser.add_argument('--list', action='store_true')
    ...: sub = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
    ...: s2 = sub.add_parser('foo')
    ...: s3 = sub.add_parser('bar')
    ...: s2.add_argument('--abc');

In [13]: parser.parse_args('--list'.split())
Out[13]: Namespace(cmd=None, list=True)
In [14]: parser.parse_args('foo --abc 2'.split())
Out[14]: Namespace(abc='2', cmd='foo', list=False)
In [15]: parser.parse_args('--list bar'.split())
Out[15]: Namespace(cmd='bar', list=True)
```

Now `cmd` is `None` when we just use `--list`, but it is also possible to use a `cmd` and `--list`.  So they are not mutually_exclusive.

I think the first way is cleaner.